# How to add a button on TinyMCE to toggle toolbar visibility?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I have 2 toolbars on my tinyMCE editor (2 rows) and I want to add a button on the first toolbar that shows/hides the 2nd toolbar.

Basically an expand / collapse button. By default the 2nd toolbar is invisible only when the button is clicked it is shown. The button should then change the icon (something like from chevron-down to chevron-up) and when clicked again should hide the 2nd toolbar.

It could also be a static button that says something like advanced options that show/hide the 2nd toolbar.

I didn't find any tinymce plugin that achieves this. Does anyone know how to implement this or a plugin that already does this (or close to it) ?

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle with the code you have so far so we don't have to recreate a TinyMCE application to be able to answer your question? :)

Answer (score 3):

TinyMCE does not have APIs to do this but you can do it based on the classes that TinyMCE places on the DIVs that contain each toolbar.

If you look at the DIVs that TinyMCE uses to render the toolbars you will see something like this:

```
<div id="mceu_41" class="mce-container mce-toolbar mce-stack-layout-item 
mce-first" role="toolbar"></div>
<div id="mceu_49" class="mce-container mce-toolbar mce-stack-layout-item 
mce-last" role="toolbar"></div>
```

(I am omitting a whole bunch of HTML in each of these DIVs)

The last row of toolbars will have the classes `mce-toolbar` and `mce-last`.  Using jQuery you can easily show/hide that DIV with the `toggle()` method.  Just make a toolbar button and add that to the first row of toolbar buttons:

```
editor.addButton('hidetoolbar2', {
    text: 'Hide Toolbar 2',
    onclick: function () { 
        $('div.mce-toolbar.mce-last').toggle();
    }
});
```

...and...

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  ...
  toolbar: [
    "hidetoolbar2 | insertfile...",
    "removeformat | fontsizeselect..."
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: @AlfaTeK - did this address your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I some code in init function:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: '.selector',
    branding: false,
    plugins: 'print preview paste searchreplace autolink directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern',
    toolbar: 'bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist | removeformat | mybutton',
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.addButton('mybutton', {
            icon: "mce-ico mce-i-preview",
            onclick: function () {
                $(editor.editorContainer).find(".mce-container.mce-menubar.mce-toolbar.mce-first").toggle();
            }
        })
    },
    init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
        $(editor.editorContainer).find(".mce-container.mce-menubar.mce-toolbar.mce-first").toggle();
    }
});
```

It's work well for me!